# Install from GitHub repo doesn't download all files

Tags: javascript, git, npm

I made some changes to an NPM package by forking the GitHub repo, and now I want to install this package to my project

I used this command to install the package:

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/username/githubreponame.git#branchname
```

It installs OO, but when I look to node_modules folder and look into the installed package, I see that not all files are installed from the GitHub repo. No JS files are installed, only License, package.json and README.md are installed, so I can't import anything from the library.

How to install all files?

Comment: I would guess you're talking about a package where the source code isn't what's in what's published, i.e. there's a `"main"` and/or `"files"` field in `package.json` pointing to the outputs of some build process. But without more information (like: _what_ package?) it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank u , this solved the problem

Comment: @jonrsharpe this seems to be the case for [this repo](https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet/blob/cee79a54b74d92edc0befc59b021434b3ced8c1d/package.json#L8) I'm trying to depend on. Do I have to fork the repo if I don't have control over it? How do I fix it if I fork it, it needs the `"main"` since it's a TypeScript repo, right?

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy that repo contains source code that needs a build process before publication. That doesn't mean anything needs _fixing_, it's a perfectly reasonable way to develop a package, but does mean you can't install it just as a git repo.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to use it as a dependency for [my website](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter.github.io/blob/62bb62e914b822a4240baf35fa7ec43db0d9f883/package.json#L24). The latest release of it on npm is old, so I wanted to depend on the git repo. Can I change some settings in my website's package.json to be able to do that? Do I need to fork that repo and change it somehow so that I can depend on that forked repo? I know I could just fork and publish my own npm package, but I don't want to pollute npm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above :
`files` in package.json , where pointing to only one folder to be installed when using npm install ,
so removing files from package.json solved the problem.

Comment: That will only install the source code, though; the files that were supposed to be built for publication won't exist. For example, you may have TypeScript files rather than JavaScript, or JavaScript with incompatible syntax.